Focusing on math and/or logic, is fictional knowledge more certain than platonic knowledge?
We all know math (and/or logic) is supposed to be one of the most certain bits of knowledge we have, but it's not absolutely certain according to many philosophers who say no knowledge is absolutely certain. Was it Dewey who said the odds are low, but we might all be making silly mathematical mistakes?
And there's a foundational effort to put the most secure knowledge at the base and build up from that, and I believe Badiou is known for believing math is such a foundation (and so is Plato of course, the most foundational apart from philosophy). So in this and related interests (let's be fairly broad, this is just one narrow example), we would want to maximize math's certainty. And notice I said certainty, not ontology.
Well, isn't it harder to be mistaken about a fictional work than a realist one? It's possible we all get Sherlock Holmes' address wrong when recollecting and reading. Maybe even Doyle meant it to be 224b and transcribed it incorrectly in the first instance. But, because authorship is primary in fictional knowledge, might it have a leg up as far as realism is concerned in this? A mathematical sense could be wrong in the same way any other sense could be wrong, such as thinking one saw a snake but it was a stick or heard something that wasn't accurate. Authorship means we grant Odysseus was supposed to and does outmaneuver the sirens. We grant there is no rung further up the ladder besides the universal skepticism for all knowledge to settle the story's plain events differently. Whereas for realism, is there not a sense of doubt that is harder to expunge? For example, had Frege instead authored a fiction about a mathematical universe where the barber paradox also held, Russell could not have shown Frege to be incorrect, just like we don't call MC Escher's drawings wrong for being paradoxical.
I rarely see this side of the debate in ficitonalism vs realism. Maybe it's implicit and I'm missing it.

Kant noticed a while ago:"A new light broke upon the first person who demonstrated the isosceles triangle... For he found... that in order to know something securely a priori he had to ascribe to the thing nothing except what followed necessarily from what he himself had put into it." The knowledge of what we ourselves conjured up is surely more certain than knowledge of what we  face externally, for the latter can obstruct us on top of our own errors. And it was Peirce on 2+2=4, "there is still a possibility that they have all committed the same error of addition every time."

This is the same kind of 'benefit' as searching under a streetlight offers. Sure, it is easier to search there, but hardly a benefit when what one is looking for is somewhere else.

@Conifold But at least there is a benefit for fictionalism, aha!


We grant there is no rung further up the ladder besides the universal skepticism for all knowledge to settle the story's plain events differently.

There is a rung further up: if the story you give contradicts itself. If at one point you say Odysseus escaped the sirens, and at another point you say Odysseus was eaten by them, then what really happened?
It's the same with mathematics. If at one point you say all numbers are rational, as the Pythagoreans before Hippasus may have, and at another point you admit the existence of a right Euclidean triangle with two equal sides, then the story you give contradicts itself, because the third side of the triangle cannot be a rational number.
So yes, it is still possible to be wrong even when you are completely making up a work of fiction.

But forcing a contemplation about "what really happened" can be an author's intent, for example Escher's drawings, Penrose's triangle, or American Psycho (movie). We don't know "what really happened", but we know there's authored, intended contradictions. And we no more doubt Bret Easton Ellis', Mary Harron's, Escher's, or Penrose's authored intents than Homer's. How does a magical siren's call work after all?  Unanswerable portions don't undermine the work (e.g. Holmes really does have magical deductive powers, how is irrelevant), and the buck stopping at authored intent seems to be consensus

@JKusin If you're drawing the line at authored intent (which is a reasonable place to draw it), what if the author didn't intend to contradict themselves? Then they're just wrong. They're not building a subtle structure through contradiction as Escher might, if they didn't intend to do that; they were just wrong.
